# Parallelize bash scripts from multiple subfolders

Tags: linux, bash, loops, parallel-processing

I am trying to parallelize multiple bash files (`script.sh`) placed in various subfolders. Specifically, I want each script to run in parallel (1 script per core), also, the script(s) only run in their respective subfolders.

In each subfolder, each script (`*.sh`) runs this line:

```
grep NODE_10123 input.i >> output.o 
grep NODE_10150 input.i >> output.o
```

So, the structure final will be:

```
├── MainFolder
│   ├── subfolder1
│   │   ├── subfolder1_script.sh
│   │   ├── input.i
│   │   ├── output.o
│   ├── subfolder2
│   │   ├── subfolder2_script.sh
│   │   ├── input.i
│   │   ├── output.o
```

I tried:

`find . -name "*_script.sh" | parallel '-type f -execdir {} '&' \;'` OR

`find . -name "*_script.sh" | parallel ::: -type f -execdir {} '&' \;`

But the script(s) don't work, or run using just one core. I want some suggestions about how to solve this problem.

Comment: You used `-execdir`. Is it necessary to first change to the directory for the function of your script?

Comment: I've never used `parallel`, but according to its [man-page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/parallel), it does not have an `-execdir` option. Didn't you get an error message?

Comment: No, just the command doesn't run.

Comment: What makes you believe you can separate the options of `find`(or just any command) across the pipe?

Comment: Please click [edit] and show the **complete** set of commands you need to type, if you are currently in your HOME directory and you want to run `subfolder1_script.sh`

Comment: I am in a 'main' folder (MainFolder(Subfolder1)(subfolder2)).

Comment: Write the exact, complete command you want to run, edit that into the question, as Mark said. Your last edit didn't address it and the question is still not clear enough. Example: `(cd subfolder1 && ./subfolder1_script.sh input1.i)`

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
for script in *_script.sh; { $script & }
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay, the scripts don't work.

Comment: @SergioBolívar: What error messages are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name "*_script.sh" | parallel
```

This will run one `*_script.sh` per CPU thread in parallel. E.g. if you have a CPU with 16 threads, it will keep 16 jobs running until all are done.

Ivan's solution with run all of the `*_script.sh` in parallel at the same time. This will often be fine, if there are not that many folders, but will overload your computer if there are 1000's of folders.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay, the scripts don't run.

Comment: @SergioBolívar: What error messages are you getting?

Comment: There are no errors, it's just that the scripts run one at a time, and not parallelized.

Answer (score 1):

From your current revision (revision 5) of the question, it seems that your directory tree structure is simple enough that there is no need to invoke `find` at all. The main issue is that your script only works in its own folder. This can be handled with the `cd` command.

The single command you want to invoke is

```
cd subfolder1 && bash subfolder1_script.sh
```

This pattern is simple enough to translate to "`parallel`-speak" as follows:

```
"cd {//} && bash {/}"
```

Basically, for a parameter that is a path, for example `subfolder1/subfolder1_script.sh`, `{//}` gives the part before the last unescaped slash (equivalent to `dirname`, in this case gives `subfolder1`), `{/}` gives the part after the last unescaped slash (equivalent to `basename`, in this case `subfolder1_script.sh`), with proper quoting applied if for example the parameter contains spaces. Other similar replacement strings can be found in [the official cheat sheet (pdf)](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_cheat.pdf).

Now we just need to provide the list of correct parameters to it, in this case it is simple enough that a glob is enough. The parameters should be put after `:::`.

Putting them together, the command you are looking for is

```
parallel "cd {//} && bash {/}" ::: */*.sh
```

The above command should be executed in your `MainFolder` in the question.

Generally, before an actual run, you want to print out the commands to double check that they're actually what you expect to run. This is especially important if the commands are destructive (for example, contains `rm`). Parallel does provide the dryrun mode to address exactly this need.

```
parallel --dryrun "cd {//} && bash {/}" ::: */*.sh
```

This will print all the commands to be executed. You should run it before running the actual command above.

Finally a side note: on Linux you may want to reconsider naming your files with a suffix `.o` because those are conventionally used for binary object files that comes from compilation and needs to be linked later.